# peewee - modify db model meta (e.g. schema) dynamically

Tags: python, database, schema, metadata, peewee

In order to insert same data to same set of tables in different schemas (data about the mobile application where app id is primary key but app is cross-platform and exists on different platforms. Schema per platfrom so pp id does not interfere for tables with it as fk).

I already has some infrastructure for it and I wasn't expecting this requirement. For me I see the easiest way is having existing model class binded to some db+schema_1+table_name insert data to first schema then somehow update classs meta to db+schema_2+table_name and call insert again.

For example, if I have the following base class with Meta set:

```
class BaseClass_1:
    class Meta_1:
        legacy_table_names = False
        database = db
        schema = 'schema_1'
```

and the another meta for another schema:

```
class Meta_2:
    legacy_table_names = False
    database = db
    schema = 'schema_2'
    primary_key = CompositeKey('app_id')
    db_table = 'table_name'
```

and the model class:

```
class Table(BaseClass_1):
    date = DateTimeField()
    app_id = TextField()

    class Meta:
        primary_key = CompositeKey('app_id')
        db_table = 'table_name'
```

then if I do the following:

```
Table.insert_many(some_data)
Table._meta = Meta_2
Table._meta = Meta_2()
```

I see that there is Meta class or object is set instead of "Metadata" objects as it was before modification. Unfortunately I did not find how to instantiate Metadata object. Is it possible, is this research direction hopeful?

Comment: Why are you using CompositeKey('app_id') ? CompositeKey is for when you have multiple columns that comprise the primary key.

Comment: I already use app_id as primary key for 'application' table. Also I have another tables referencing this key, including table "supported_platforms". Now I receiving app data for some of supported platforms also. So I can not just add 'platform' column into 'application' table - because it will require to add 'platform' colum to 'supported_platforms' (its colums are date, app_id, platform_id) and it will become messy. At the same time I can not just drop 'supported_platforms' since I recive details data not for all supported platforms. Does it make sence?